# Command to close an application of console?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I need to close the console when the user selects a menu option.

I tried using `close()` but it did not work..

how can I do this?

Comment: Just curious: Which object did you try calling .Close() on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify the exit code of a console application in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

`Environment.Exit` and `Application.Exit`

`Environment.Exit(0)` is cleaner.

http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

Comment: Is there an updated link for the geekswithblogs article? I'm not finding it on the Internet Archive, been trying to search for parts of that URL.

Answer (score 35):

By close, do you mean you want the current instance of the console app to close, or do you want the application process, to terminate? Missed that all important exit code:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Or to close the current instance of the form:

```
this.Close();
```

Useful [link](http://www.dev102.com/2008/06/24/how-do-you-exit-your-net-application/).

Answer (score 6):

You can Try This

```
Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 //How to start another application from the current application
 Process runProg = new Process();
 runProg.StartInfo.FileName = pathToFile; //the path of the application
 runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = genArgs; //any arguments you want to pass
 runProg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 runProg.Start();

 //How to end the same application from the current application
 int IDstring = System.Convert.ToInt32(runProg.Id.ToString());
 Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(IDstring);
 tempProc.CloseMainWindow();
 tempProc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

`return;` will exit a method in C#.

See code snippet below

```
using System;

namespace Exercise_strings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Input string separated by -");

            var stringInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing entered");
                return;
            }
}
```

So in this case if a user enters a null string or whitespace, the use of the return method terminates the Main method elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

So you didn't say you wanted the application to quit or exit abruptly, so as another option, perhaps just have the response loop end out elegantly. (I am assuming you have a while loop waiting for user instructions. This is some code from a project I just wrote today.

```
        Console.WriteLine("College File Processor");
        Console.WriteLine("*************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("(H)elp");
        Console.WriteLine("Process (W)orkouts");
        Console.WriteLine("Process (I)nterviews");
        Console.WriteLine("Process (P)ro Days");
        Console.WriteLine("(S)tart Processing");
        Console.WriteLine("E(x)it");
        Console.WriteLine("*************************************");

        string response = "";
        string videotype = "";
        bool starting = false;
        bool exiting = false;

        response = Console.ReadLine();

        while ( response != "" )
        {
            switch ( response  )
            {
                case "H":
                case "h":
                    DisplayHelp();
                    break;

                case "W":
                case "w":
                    Console.WriteLine("Video Type set to Workout");
                    videotype = "W";
                    break;

                case "I":
                case "i":
                    Console.WriteLine("Video Type set to Interview");
                    videotype = "I";
                    break;

                case "P":
                case "p":
                    Console.WriteLine("Video Type set to Pro Day");
                    videotype = "P";
                    break;

                case "S":
                case "s":
                    if ( videotype == "" )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Select Video Type Before Starting");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
                        starting = true;
                    }
                    break;

                case "E":
                case "e":
                    Console.WriteLine("Good Bye!");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    exiting = true;
                    break;
            }

            if ( starting || exiting)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                response = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        if ( starting )
        {
            ProcessFiles();
        }
```