# exit console app after completing process

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Hello my console app is for downloading html files and then sending it to a txt file, after the process is complete I would like the app to verify if the file was created and then close the program after telling the user that the page downloaded. I would like to ask how to verify if file exists and then how to exit the app.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Valid Webpage URL such as http://wwww.google.com, this tool will download the HTML into a .txt file");
        string webPage = Console.ReadLine();
        Uri uriResult;
        bool result = Uri.TryCreate(webPage, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
            && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //DownloadsWebpage
        string reply = client.DownloadString(webPage);

        Console.WriteLine(reply);
        //Location of file here
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid address to save the .txt file such as C:\\Users\\Public\\String.txt, then press any button to exit");
        string txtDir = Console.ReadLine();
        File.WriteAllText(txtDir, reply);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are you talking about closing the window when the program exits? That may be a window manager setting, "close on exit" or similar.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your plans! What's preventing you from implementing them?

Comment: File.Exists() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx is a good starting point for what you are looking for

Comment: Has been answered similarly here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682408/command-to-close-an-application-of-console

Comment: You could replace your last `Console.ReadLine();` with: `if (File.Exists(txtDir)) Console.WriteLine("File was created successfully"); else Console.WriteLine("File creation failed"); Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit..."); Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: thank you all, are there any resources for capturing url exceptions and file directory exceptions?

Comment: @ProTalz you can always cat any exception via a try catch block. If needed you can have multiple catch blocks that catch more specific types of exceptions but using the type `Exception` to catch all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For verifying a file exists, there is a method called `File.Exists()` which would tell you if it has been created. Then once your program gets to the end of `main` it will just edit automatically.

Something like the following after your `File.WriteAllText(txtDir, reply);` may be:

```
if (!File.Exists(txtDir)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Some error creating file");
}
```

When you want to exit, just let you program close when it reaches the end of `main` or use `Enviroment.Exit(0)`

Answer (score 1):

To check if the file Exists and exit:

if( System.IO.File.Exists(pathname))

{

```
 System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

}

// Do something else here to recover