# c# - how to close console without closing application through winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, pipe, console-application

I've created an add-in for a program that starts up a console using the following code block below however I don't know how to close the console window without closing the entire program. I've found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682408/command-to-close-an-application-of-console) but when I try `Environment.Exit(0)` it closes my entire program.

I've been on this for a couple of days however I'm not having any luck with this. Long story short, I am creating the console to pipe information between it and another process. Once it receives the information, I'd like it to close and resume to the parent process. I am sure this is an easy thing to but I'm not finding the solution on my own.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    AllocConsole(); 
} 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] 
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Comment: You should be able to call `FreeConsole()` to release the console window. See duplicate for details. That said, I find that alloc/free console is generally a very poor way to do this sort of thing. It's not clear from your question why you are creating the console, but more likely you should just be using the `Process` class and redirecting stdout, stderr, and stdin as needed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, The `FreeConsole()` worked. I tried using the `Process` class but I was having issues with it. I'll give it another shot. I'm creating a console to pipe information back and forth between to open programs on a single computer using named pipes. kinda like making Excel and Word talk to each other while both are open.  Something similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication)