# C# Console close when someone types the wrong answer

Tags: c#, console-application

I've been trying to figure out how to get my console to close when someone finally types the wrong answer (in my quiz)?

I've tried Environment.Exit(); but it doesn't work...
It gives me the error: "no overload for method 'Exit' takes 0 arguments.

Here's a bit of my code. I've marked with a comment where I'd want the quit code to be:

```
Console.WriteLine("In what country was Adolf Hitler born?");

string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

if (Answers.AnswerOne.Equals(userAnswer))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! {0} is the correct answer!", Answers.AnswerOne);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n(Press Enter to move on to the next question...)");
}
else if (!Answers.AnswerOne.Equals(userAnswer))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry! You wrote the wrong answer!\nThe correct answer was {0}.", Answers.AnswerOne);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n(Press Enter to exit...)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    //EXIT CONSOLE
}
```

Otherwise, the code runs perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use `Console.ReadKey();` nad try `Environment.Exit(0);` or `Environment.Exit(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is 100% correct. `Environment.Exit()` needs to be called with a parameter.

Try [`Environment.Exit(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx). The `.Exit()` method takes an int value to indicate the 'exit code'.

> Exit code to be given to the operating system. Use 0 (zero) to indicate that the process completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find multiple answers here: [How do I specify the exit code of a console application in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net)

Google is your friend. :)

As for Environment.Exit(int exitCode):

```
// Summary:
//     Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified
//     exit code.
//
// Parameters:
//   exitCode:
//     Exit code to be given to the operating system.
```

0 is the default exit code when nothing went wrong.