# How do I make my console application return an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, exit-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I specify the exit code of a console application in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net)

I need to have a console app that returns a value to the caller (I will call it by a PowerShell script).

How can I change the entry-point to the console app? (And would this be enough to be able to consume return values from the console app?)

Comment: Presumably you mean exit code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are three obvious choices for returning information:

- Through the exit code of the process. This is pretty easy, as you can just declare that the `Main` method returns `int`, and whatever you return from the method will be the exit code of the process. It's a bit unusual though, as the convention is for anything other than 0 to indicate some kind of error.
- Through console output, consumed by the calling process
- Through file output, e.g. the calling process specifies a filename, and your process writes to that file.

If you're consuming this from PowerShell though, why not write a [Cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? That should intergrate with PS rather more smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the main method to return an int.

See the sample

```
    static int Main()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your Main method with an integer return value

```
static int Main(string[] args) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [%ERRORLEVEL%](http://csharp.2000things.com/2010/06/27/the-return-value-from-main-sets-errorlevel-variable-in-windows/) environment variable.