# How to exit a method

Tags: c#, console-application, exit

How to exit a method, instead of raise new Exception or return in console application.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[i + 1].ToString()))
{
    inputFilePath = args[i + 1].ToString();
}
else
{
   //code to exit console application run
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it any other way

Comment: not sure what you want, Application.Exit will stop your program straight away (as said above). However: if you start your application inside a console and you exit, you will return to the console (so the black screen with the text will remain). That is simply how windows work and you can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to exit your program do `return` if you want to return an exit status ([as this SO answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net)) make your main's return type int and return an int.