# Gitlab-CI succeeds on non-zero exit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab-CI seems allow the build to succeed even though the script is returning a non-zero exit. I have the following minimal `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
# Run linter
lint:
  stage: build
  script:
    - exit 1
```

Producing the following result:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.1.0 (081978aa)
  on gitlab-runner 72348d01
Using Shell executor...
Running on [hostname]
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 9f6f309 Still having problems with gitlab-runner
From https://[repo]
   9f6f309..96fc77b  dev        -> origin/dev
Checking out 96fc77bb as dev...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ exit 1
Job succeeded
```

Running on GitLab Community Edition 9.5.5 with gitlab-runner version 11.1.0. Closest [post](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/1311) doesn't propose a resolution nor does this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20731). A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619212/how-to-fail-a-build-on-gitlab-ci-shell-runner) shows this setup should fail.

What are the conditions of failing a job? Isn't it a non-zero return code?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was `su` was wrapped to call [ksu](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_commands/ksu.html) as the shared machines are authenticated using [Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/). In that case the wrapped `ksu` succeeds even though the script command might fail, indicating the job succeeded. This affected `gitlab-runner` since the shell executor was running `su` to run as the indicated user.