# Error handling using process c#

Tags: c#, error-handling, process, console-application

I have created a console application using C#, and I called it from another Windows Forms application using `Process`.

Below is my code for Console Application

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // ...my code
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Below is code for call the exe of Console application from the window application using process

```
    public void CallExe()
    {
        try
        {                              
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Debug\console1.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "My args";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.Start();              
            proc.WaitForExit();              
            string stdout = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string stderr = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            proc = null;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Now, What I want is when any error comes from the console application
it directly throws to my window application catch block. Or can I get error message to my window application which is thrown by console application ?

Comment: You can't catch an error that occurs in another process, but you _can_ return an exit code from the console app.

Comment: Can I get ex.message from console application ?

Comment: You can [specify an exit code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net) which is an integer, and pick it up from [`Process.ExitCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx). Or you could read/write whatever you want from/to StandardOutput or StandardError

Comment: what you CAN do is interprocess communication: catch the exception in your console process, have a pipe to your other process, and write a serialized exception onto that pipe ... read it on the other side, and... maybe even give commands back on what to do next?!

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: Thanks a lot. Can I have small example for that ?

Comment: an IPC example? ... here you go... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 10):

You are not capturing anything from the process you run. You can't call `ReadToEnd` on both streams as it will block one or the other from producing results. If you want to capture both the stdout as stderr you'll need to subscribe to the [DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) events and store the data from the event arguments.

The following code in your windows forms application should look like this:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"console.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "My args";
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

//store outcome of process
var errors = new StringBuilder();
var output = new StringBuilder();
var hadErrors = false;

// raise events
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// capture normal output
proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, d) => { 
    output.Append(d.Data); 
};

// Capture error output
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, d) => { 
    if (!hadErrors)
    {
        hadErrors = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Data);
    }
    errors.Append(d.Data); 
};

proc.Start();
// start listening on the stream
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

proc.WaitForExit();
string stdout = output.ToString();
string stderr = errors.ToString();

if (proc.ExitCode !=0 || hadErrors)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error:" + stderr);
}
```

In the test console application you can now write to stderr and set an Exitcode if you like:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ready ...");
    var cmd = Console.ReadLine();
    if (cmd == "e")
    {
        throw new Exception("boom");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success!");
    }
    Environment.ExitCode = 0;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // write to stderr
    Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message);
    // exit code to 1
    Environment.ExitCode = 1;
}
```