# Application exit code always return 0

Tags: c#, windows, vb6, exit

We have a legacy VB6 application that runs a separate C# EXE. The VB6 application relies on the C# application to perform a particular task. When the task is done successfully it will return with exit code 0, or 1 if failure.

This works well on our development machines (yes, we tried on more than 1 machine). But, when we tried it on the client machine it always returns a 0 exit code no matter the result of the task.

The really strange part is that this scenario has been working perfectly for about 8 months until this first happenned.

We even tried to make a simple C# 'runner app' that only calls an exe and catches its exit code. Again, it worked fine on our development machine but always return 0 on the client machine. So, we concluded that the problem is not in the VB6 program.

This is the C# 'runner app' code snippet that call the .exe program:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process installProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
installProcess.StartInfo.FileName = this.textBox1.Text;
installProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = this.textBox2.Text;
installProcess.Start();
installProcess.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("Exit code : " + installProcess.ExitCode.ToString());
```

And this is the C# code snippet that exit the program with custom exit code:

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

Well, we suspect there's some configuration on the client machine OS that causes this strange behavior on the client machine.

Comment: Have you tried directly running the other application from command prompt with invalid arguments and verifying return code is 1?

Comment: can you please describe how to verify it?

Comment: `echo %errorlevel%` is one way.

Comment: `Environment.Exit(1);` is *not* usually the preferred way to exit an exe with a return code; usually you should unwind to your `static int Main()` method and simply `return 0;` or `return 1;` (perhaps this one inside a `catch` block) - hard to know if that is the reason without trying it.

Comment: we solved this by setting the `Environment` exit code property `Environment.ExitCode = 1` , is this an acceptable way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment from Michael Gosselin on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net), it is critical to compile your project as a "console application" and not as a "windows application".