# C# main function being void

Tags: c#, .net

In both C and C++ the main function is of type int and at the end of the main method it returns 0. If the program returns 0 I know that the program was successful. But in c# the main is of type void by default (I guess you could change it to an int and return 0 aswell) so how can I know that the program was successful in this case? Do I have to debug or do some debug writelines to really 
clarify that the program was successfull in this case where the main method is void?

Comment: Know that your program was successful from where?

Comment: [The `Environment.Exit` method takes one parameter, which becomes the process exit code.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

Comment: More discussion on Environment.Exit ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net

Answer (score 6):

The `Main` method can return `void` or an `int`:

```
static int Main()
{
    //... 
    return 0;
}
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/main-return-values).