# C# program that leaves untouched errorlevel

Tags: c#, windows, error-handling

Is there a way to read `ERRORLEVEL` from an C# so you can return it and keeps unchanged when finishes?

It seems that `Environment.ExitCode` begins with 0 when the program starts. This program always writes 0.

> To **too lazy; didn't read** people: **the following code is not the
>   program I want to write**, but a test to prove that
>   `Environment.ExitCode` is not inherited from `errorlevel`,
>   `%errorlevel%` or any previous exit code just in case of doubt.

```
using System;

namespace test {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",Environment.ExitCode);
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to write a program that, when used in a batch, doesn't interfere with the current errorlevel so it can be used afterwards. I know you can save it and restore it inside the batch...

```
...
command1 with options "or not"
set elsaved=%errorlevel%
my_cs_program run without telling it which errorlevel is
REM Damn, I cleared errorlevel, thank science I saved it before
call :setel %elsaved%
...
goto :eof

:setel
exit /b %1
```

... but it's a nuisance. It would be better if the invocation left errorlevel alone.

```
...
        static void Main() {
...
            var parent_cmd_errorlevel=exotic_funtion();
...
            Environment.ExitCode = parent_cmd_errorlevel;
...
```

This way I don't have to mind about it in the batch.

---

**tl;dr**: Is it possible to write a C# program **transparent** to errorlevel? If not in C#, is there any other language? What one? More generally: can a cmd.exe child process obtain the errorlevel of its parent? Maybe `wmic` would help?

---

To **downvoters**/**duplicate-voters**: I *know* how to *specify the exit code of a console application in .NET*:

```
...
        static void Main() {
...
            Environment.ExitCode = whatever;
...
```

Or

```
...
        static int Main() {
...
            return(whatever);
...
```

Am I wrong? If you are not interested in this problem, please leave the question alone but AFAIK this has not been asked in SO or another SE KB.

Comment: 0 is the default, no-error indication. If you set it, your application should terminate. So... why do you want to `read` it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify the exit code of a console application in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. As is, this feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - since we can't see the context.

Comment: This code just proves that, without touching it, `Environment.ExitCode` begins as 0. If I was able to _get_ it then I would _set_ it.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ERRORLEVEL` is built into the command interpreter. It's not, for example, some form of environment variable. You can't access whatever it was left set to following the previous program's exit.

Comment: To downvoters/dupevoters, please read my updates.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the ERRORLEVEL from the last program, but you could pass it as argument and then set it again:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Environment.ExitCode = int.Parse(args[0]);
    }
}
```

And then call it in your batch like this:

```
cd "some path that returns an error"
.\Console1App.exe %errorlevel%

REM Print the error code of the cd command
echo %errorlevel%
```

---

Note that this only works if the %errorlevel%  *environment* variable is not set. The way CMD works is that it will pass the actual errorlevel as fallback when %errorlevel% is not set

Comment: [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743) by Raymond Chen might be instructive.

Comment: @Freggar OK. If you say it's impossible I'll take your word but in such cases it comes to my mind that quote from _The Princess Bride_: «Nonsense. You're only saying that because no one ever has.» ᴶᵘˢᵗ ᵏᶦᵈᵈᶦⁿᵍ

Comment: The ERRORLEVEL of the last executed command is internally saved by the interpreter (CMD) but never actually written to any enviroment variable like in UNIX systems. It's just a quirk of CMD that it subsitutes `%errorlevel%` with `ERRORLEVEL` when the enviroment variable is not set.